# What would be a good two man combining melee weapon be?

Tags: magic, warfare, weapons

I was playing Dark Souls II, and came across these 2 ass-hats. (Disclaimer, that is not me, I just pulled that from Google). They then inspired to make this question. 
[image: Screenshot]

Imagine a race of humanoids, 8 feet tall, with extra-human strength, capable of lugging around 100 - 200 kilograms of equipment. What could be a good weapon, that can be combined from smaller designed-for-this-purpose-weapon.

Notes:

- Late Medieval tech levels
- Low powered magic very common and cheap, high powered magic very rare and expensive
- They will be fighting with and against various other fantasy animal peoples and humans.
- For a weapon this large, the only practical context would be for use in war or sieges.
- The weapon can be split in to 2 or more smaller parts, and each part can be used as a weapon on itself, but the combined weapon should be as strong, or stronger than the sum of its parts.
- The weapon can be either melee or ranged

Comment: Honestly, the best combination is a guy in front with a shield and a guy in back with a spear. But I assume that's not what you're going for.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh that could work as well

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I think there used to be separate shield carriers for bowmen and, of course, charioteers. So bowman plus "assistant" is actually quite common combo. Probably because it was a noblemans weapon? (Talking about ancient era here.)

Comment: How about http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion_Swords ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well okay, besides the tonfas, I have another idea: Segmented Shields, similar to the DS2 Ozma and Reeves greatshields that you display above, but with a twist.

Basically, the shields can have interlocking mechanisms (or just be shaped to interlock) on both sides, whereby they fit together if held side by side. Imagine a row of these soldiers in Roman testudo formation, their shields forming a sealed, impenetrable wall that relentlessly advances onto their enemies. If you put slits in the shields, and some sort of hinge for them to be held ahead of the user, they could even be used as mobile cover for archers or crossbowmen. A large formation of such shield users would be akin to a walking castle.

Comment: Apparently you have never tried getting even half a dozen people to carry a sofa or table about to think of locking a thousand shields on a battlefield.

Comment: @Oldcat Did these half-dozen people have military training for carrying a sofa?

Comment: I would pay to see military sofa carrying training.

Answer (score 3):

One of the first things that came to mind for me, thanks to my friend, who knows who s/he is, is a pair of combining tonfas.
[image]

The tonfa is modified to have an additional handle on the other side. In a squad of 2, each of them holds one tonfa and a big shield. The tonfas then have some sort of mechanism that allows the two of them to combine together, which then turns into a battering ram. They can then use it to knock down walls, or against large creatures such as themselves, wargolems, grounded dragons and the like.

Comment: Yay, I am appreciated. :D

Comment: what's the scale here? With only the woodgrain to go by, those look about a foot long to me -- and it's hard to imagine two one-foot-long pieces of wood knocking down a wall, so I think I'm missing something. Or are those scale models?